# AWS AppFlow and Terraform Integration

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, terraform-provider-aws, sap, amazon-appflow

In our new project, we are utilizing AWS AppFlow to pull data from SAP through OData Connectors. For IaC, **Terraform **is utilized.

My questions are :-

1. Does AppFlow integrate with TerraForm?
2. AWS AppFlow is a "No-code, low-code" Visual interface to move data between SaaS applications. When we develop a flow, does AWS provide the back script automatically (Eg:- like in Glue Studio, after creating a visual flow, we can extract the backend script).
3. Does AWS AppFlow integrate with CodeCommit?

I created a Flow with AWS AppFlow visually. Unable to extract the backend code. Not sure how the code can be stitched with Terraform

Comment: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/appflow_flow

Comment: My question is more about Appflow's integration with GitHub / CodeCommit from the visual interface. From Glue Studio, we can directly integrate code on to Github / Code Commit. Similar to this, I do not see AppFlow's integration to code repository from the Visual Interface.